# Is $e^z + \overline{z}^2$ holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can a sum of a holomorphic and non-holomorphic functions be itself holomorphic? As I understand, $\overline{z} ^2$ is not holomorphic?

Comment: If it was then the non-holomorphic function would be the difference of two holomorphic functions which is holomorphic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference of two holomorphic functions is holomorphic. Is $(e^z + \bar z^2) - e^z$ holomorphic?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I calculated $\overline{z} ^2$ is not holomorphic because it doesn't satisfy the C-R conditions.